# What's the advantage of Selector in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, io, nio

As I know we can register all SocketChannels into one single Selector on the server side, but why? It's there any difference with adding these SocketChannels into a ArrayList, then I iterate this List manually?

Comment: For non-blocking events it is easier to use a selector and monitor channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors allow the JVM implementation to work efficiently with the operating systems select/epoll/kqueue (or equivalent) mechanism by pushing the work down into the appropriate kernel/driver. The modern OS implementation of such functions is generally considered to be O(1).

That is, Java itself can "sleep" until the underlying OS signals one or more channels - which is configured and reported in Java NIO via Selectors.

When in a loop with the Selector, select will "block" until there is a channel change - so keeping with the Selectors allows one to efficiently find the relevant channels and handle them. It's all part of the above goal to keep the "per-event" processing O(c), where c << n, when dealing with n channels.

Comment: Hi, is that something like event-driven?

Comment: @Alexis Well, sorta. One could say that Selector.select "waits for events".

Answer (score 1):

Selectors provide low-latency transfer of control.  If you periodically wake up and walk a list of channels, then your average latency is T/2, and the only way to reduce that is to spend more time walking the list;for very small T you're effectively busy looping.  With a selector, the average latency is smaller and there's no cycles wasted maintaining or walking the list.

Comment: hi, do you mean if I use Selector, I don't need a infinite loop to iterate the channel List since Selector.select() will block the loop, so it reduce the latency and the usage of cpu resource?

Comment: @Alexis, since selectors are built-in to the OS's thread scheduler you don't need to trade-off latency against CPU usage.